# Tensorflow: Efficient multinomial sampling (Theano x50 faster?)

Tags: performance, tensorflow, sampling, multinomial

I want to be able to sample from a multinomial distribution **very** efficiently and apparently my TensorFlow code is very... very slow...

The idea is that, I have:

- A vector: `counts = [40, 50, 26, ..., 19]` for example
- A matrix of probabilities: `probs = [[0.1, ..., 0.5], ... [0.3, ..., 0.02]]` such that `np.sum(probs, axis=1) = 1`

Let's say `len(counts) = N` and `len(probs) = (N, 50)`. What I want to do is (in our example):

- sample 40 times from the first probability vector of the matrix `probs`
- sample 50 times from the second probability vector of the matrix `probs`
- ...
- sample 19 times from the Nth probability vector of the matrix `probs`

such that my final matrix looks like (for example):
`A = [[22, ... 13], ..., [12, ..., 3]]` where `np.sum(A, axis=1) == counts`
(i.e the sum over each row = the number in the corresponding row of `counts` vector)

Here is my TensorFlow code sample:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as ds
import time

nb_distribution = 100 # number of probability distributions

counts = np.random.randint(2000, 3500, size=nb_distribution) # define number of counts (vector of size 100 with int in 2000, 3500)
# print(u[:40]) # should be the same as the output of print(np.sum(res, 1)[:40]) in the tf.Session()

# probsn is a matrix of probability:
# each row of probsn contains a vector of size 30 that sums to 1
probsn = np.random.uniform(size=(nb_distribution, 30))
probsn /= np.sum(probsn, axis=1)[:, None]

counts = tf.Variable(counts, dtype=tf.float32)
probs = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(probsn.astype(np.float32)))

# sample from the multinomial
dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=counts, probs=probs)
out = dist.sample()

start = time.time()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(out)
    # print(np.sum(res, 1)[:40])
print(time.time() - start)
```

**elapsed time**: 0.12 seconds

My equivalent code in **Theano**:

```py
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano.tensor import _shared

nb_distribution = 100 # number of probability distributions

counts = np.random.randint(2000, 3500, size=nb_distribution)
#print(u[:40]) # should be the same as the output of print(np.sum(v_sample(), 1)[:40])

counts = _shared(counts) # define number of counts (vector of size 100 with int in 2000, 3500)

# probsn is a matrix of probability:
# each row of probsn contains a vector that sums to 1
probsn = np.random.uniform(size=(nb_distribution, 30)) 
probsn /= np.sum(probsn, axis=1)[:, None]
probsn = _shared(probsn)

from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams

np_rng = np.random.RandomState(12345)
theano_rng = RandomStreams(np_rng.randint(2 ** 30))

v_sample = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=theano_rng.multinomial(n=counts, pvals=probsn))

start_t = time.time()
out = np.sum(v_sample(), 1)[:40]
# print(out)
print(time.time() - start_t)
```

**elapsed time**: 0.0025 seconds

Theano is like 100x faster... Is there something wrong with my TensorFlow code? How can I sample from a multinomial distribution efficiently in TensorFlow?

Comment: Creating a TF session takes some time. For a fair comparison, you should move the `start` into the `with tf.Session` block.

Comment: @xdurch0 and first calls are typically slower, so you should start your timing after a warm-up period

Comment: @xdurch0 you're totally right I didn't notice that but still the problem is real. I had this problem on a real project. I've just made up these examples so you can try it by yourself too.
Moving the timer the theano code runs in **0.002 to 0.003 secondes** while the tensorflow code runs in **0.08 to 0.09 seconds**... A big difference when it comes to real project with lot's of data...
anyone have an idea? According to the profiler Tensorflow spend time creating OneHot vectors...
user1735003: Yes I've also noticed it but still... the problem seems real

Comment: I've managed to built my own multinomial sampling that is **5x** faster than the one implemented in TensorFlow... Yet it is still far behind the Theano's implementation. I have used `tf.scatter_nd` for my implementation. If nobody finds something better I will post my code.

The things is that in TF they do that in `_sample_n` [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/multinomial.py):

`math_ops.reduce_sum(array_ops.one_hot(x, depth=k), axis=-2)`

i.e they upsample nd-tensor -> (n+1)d-tensor before applying a `reduce sum`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the TensorFlow multinomial `sample()` method actually uses the method calls `_sample_n()`. This method is defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/multinomial.py). As we can see in the code to sample from the multinomial the code produces a matrix of one_hot for **each row** and then reduce the matrix into a vector by summing over the rows:

`math_ops.reduce_sum(array_ops.one_hot(x, depth=k), axis=-2)`

It is inefficient because it uses extra memory. To avoid this I have used the
`tf.scatter_nd` function. Here is a fully runnable example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as ds
import time

tf.reset_default_graph()

nb_distribution = 100 # number of probabilities distribution

u = np.random.randint(2000, 3500, size=nb_distribution) # define number of counts (vector of size 100 with int in 2000, 3500)

# probsn is a matrix of probability:
# each row of probsn contains a vector of size 30 that sums to 1
probsn = np.random.uniform(size=(nb_distribution, 30))
probsn /= np.sum(probsn, axis=1)[:, None]

counts = tf.Variable(u, dtype=tf.float32)
probs = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(probsn.astype(np.float32)))

# sample from the multinomial
dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=counts, probs=probs)
out = dist.sample()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(out) # if remove this line the code is slower...
    start = time.time()
    res = sess.run(out)
    print(time.time() - start)
    print(np.all(u == np.sum(res, axis=1)))
```

This code took 0.05 seconds to compute

```py
def vmultinomial_sampling(counts, pvals, seed=None):
    k = tf.shape(pvals)[1]
    logits = tf.expand_dims(tf.log(pvals), 1)

    def sample_single(args):
        logits_, n_draw_ = args[0], args[1]
        x = tf.multinomial(logits_, n_draw_, seed)
        indices = tf.cast(tf.reshape(x, [-1,1]), tf.int32)
        updates = tf.ones(n_draw_) # tf.shape(indices)[0]
        return tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, [k])

    x = tf.map_fn(sample_single, [logits, counts], dtype=tf.float32)

    return x

xx = vmultinomial_sampling(u, probsn)
# check = tf.expand_dims(counts, 1) * probs

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(xx) # if remove this line the code is slower...
    start_t = time.time()
    res = sess.run(xx)
    print(time.time() -start_t)
    #print(np.sum(res, axis=1))
    print(np.all(u == np.sum(res, axis=1)))
```

This code took 0.016 seconds

The drawback is that my code doesn't actually parallelize the computation (even though `parallel_iterations` parameter is set to 10 by default in `map_fn`, putting it to 1 doesn't change anything...)

Maybe someone will find something better because it is still very slow as compare to Theano's implementation (due to the fact that it doesn't take advantage of the parallelization... and yet, here, parallelization makes sense because sampling one row is indenpendent from sampling another one...)